# Attempting to install Python PIL module fails with "Non-zero exit code"

Tags: python, pycharm

I really don't get why Python is so difficult to get up and running properly.

Anyway, I've just fresh installed Python 3.7 and PyCharm. I want to get the Python Imaging Library working within my project, but when I try to install it using PyCharm I get the following error:

```
pip install PIL
Non-zero exit code (1)
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe'.

Command output:
Collecting PIL

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've attempted to run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` from a CMD prompt, but I then get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I just tried to install NumPy using the exact same method for PIL and Numpy installed without any issues whatsoever. This leads me to think that maybe PIL isn't supported for Python 3.7?

Can someone explain to me what the issue is here and help me with importing modules into my PyCharm project?

Answer (score 0):

PIL is not maintained anymore. You can use Pillow instead, a more active fork of PIL.

```
pip install Pillow
```